# Python and SQLite3 SELECT statement

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I was using the SELECT method in a function. I tried to Select all the rows where "First_Name," a column, is equal to "FirstName," a variable. However, it gives me an error saying that "FirstName" is not a column. I have no idea how to fix this issue. I have copy-pasted the SELECT statement below.

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM AccountLists WHERE First_Name = FirstName AND Last_Name = LastName')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use **?** notation, like this:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM AccountLists WHERE First_Name=? AND Last_Name=?', (FirstName, LastName))
```

The **?** is a placeholder that you use wherever you want to use a value and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s `execute()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. However,  I have found another problem. I used the exact same code but removed the last name portion so the statement looks like:

c.execute('SELECT * FROM AccountLists WHERE First_Name=?', (FirstName))

Comment: @AnshKumar You forgot put "`,`" after FirstName - to create a tuple: `c.execute('SELECT * FROM AccountLists WHERE First_Name=?', (FirstName, ))`